# Weighted sum of variables by groups with data.table

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table, weighted

I am looking for a solution to compute weighted sum of some variables by groups with data.table. I hope the example is clear enough.

```
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(matrix(1:200, nrow = 10))
dt[, gr := c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5))]
dt[, w := 2]

# Error: object 'w' not found
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x * w)),
   .SDcols = paste0("V", 1:4)]

# Error: object 'w' not found
dt[, lapply(.SD * w, sum),
   .SDcols = paste0("V", 1:4)]

# This works with out groups
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x * dt$w)),
   .SDcols = paste0("V", 1:4)]

# It does not work by groups
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x * dt$w)),
   .SDcols = paste0("V", 1:4), keyby = gr]

# The result to be expected
dt[, list(V1 = sum(V1 * w),
          V2 = sum(V2 * w),
          V3 = sum(V3 * w),
          V4 = sum(V4 * w)), keyby = gr]

### from Aruns answer
dt[, lapply(.SD[, paste0("V", 1:4), with = F],
            function(x) sum(x*w)), by=gr]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Final attempt (copying Roland's answer :))

Copying @Roland's excellent answer:

```
print(dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x, w) sum(x*w), w=w), by=gr][, w := NULL])
```

---

#### still not the most efficient one: (second attempt)

Following @Roland's comment, it's indeed faster to do the operation on all columns and then just remove the unwanted ones (as long as the operation itself is not time consuming, which is the case here).

```
dt[, {lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x*w))}, by=gr][, w := NULL][]
```

For some reason, `w` seems to be not found when I don't use `{}`.. No idea why though.

---

#### old (inefficient) answer:

(Subsetting can be costly if there are too many groups)

You can do this without using `.SDcols` and then removing it while providing it to `lapply` as follows:

```
dt[, lapply(.SD[, -1, with=FALSE], function(x) sum(x*w)), by=gr]
#    gr V1  V2  V3  V4
# 1:  1 20 120 220 320
# 2:  2 70 170 270 370
```

`.SDcols` makes `.SD` *without* the `w` column. So, it's not possible to multiply with `w` as it doesn't exist within the scope of .SD environment then.

Comment: I suspect it might be faster (due to data.table optimization) to just lapply over all columns and simply remove the `w*w` column afterwards.

Comment: Roland, seems so. for some reason `w` is not found unless I use `{}`. I'll make an edit. Maybe you follow why...

Comment: `print(dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x, w) sum(x*w), w=w), by=gr][, w := NULL])`

Comment: that's awesome indeed. much faster as well. hadn't thought about the `lapply` optional argument to FUN.

Comment: Arun, it seems I will be using your ineffective solution. It is because I have to do the weighted sum only for small subset of all variables. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @djhurio, no you can still use it by doing: `dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x, w) sum(x*w), w=w), by=gr, .SDcols=c("w", "V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")][, w := NULL]`

Comment: @Arun, thanks! The data set in my case is not so big. So I do not see dramatic time lag with the ineffective solution. I will use it because the syntax is shorter and more readable.