# R data.table: subgroup weighted percent of group

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I have a `data.table` like:

```
library(data.table)
widgets <- data.table(serial_no=1:100, 
                      color=rep_len(c("red","green","blue","black"),length.out=100),
                      style=rep_len(c("round","pointy","flat"),length.out=100),
                      weight=rep_len(1:5,length.out=100) )
```

Although I am not sure this is the most `data.table` way, I can calculate subgroup frequency by group using `table` and `length` in a single step-- for example, to answer the question "What percent of red widgets are round?"

**edit:** this code does not provide the right answer

```
# example A
widgets[, list(style = unique(style), 
               style_pct_of_color_by_count = 
                 as.numeric(table(style)/length(style)) ), by=color]

#    color  style style_pct_of_color_by_count
# 1:   red  round                        0.32
# 2:   red pointy                        0.32
# 3:   red   flat                        0.36
# 4: green pointy                        0.32
# ...
```

But I can't use that approach to answer questions like "By weight, what percent of red widgets are round?" I can only come up with a two-step approach:

```
# example B
widgets[,list(cs_weight=sum(weight)),by=list(color,style)][,list(style, style_pct_of_color_by_weight=cs_weight/sum(cs_weight)),by=color]

#    color  style style_pct_of_color_by_weight
# 1:   red  round                    0.3466667
# 2:   red pointy                    0.3466667
# 3:   red   flat                    0.3066667
# 4: green pointy                    0.3333333
# ...
```

I'm looking for a single-step approach to B, and A if improvable, in an explanation that deepens my understanding of `data.table` syntax for by-group operations.  Please note that this question is different from [Weighted sum of variables by groups with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743745/weighted-sum-of-variables-by-groups-with-data-table) because mine involves subgroups and avoiding multiple steps.  TYVM.

Comment: Looking at response from @Frank below I noticed that my attempt A is not only awkward but incorrect -- for example, I checked `widgets[,sum(style=="round" & color=="red")/sum(color=="red")] # 0.36`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is almost a single step:

```
# A
widgets[,{
    totwt = .N
    .SD[,.(frac=.N/totwt),by=style]
},by=color]
    # color  style frac
 # 1:   red  round 0.36
 # 2:   red pointy 0.32
 # 3:   red   flat 0.32
 # 4: green pointy 0.36
 # 5: green   flat 0.32
 # 6: green  round 0.32
 # 7:  blue   flat 0.36
 # 8:  blue  round 0.32
 # 9:  blue pointy 0.32
# 10: black  round 0.36
# 11: black pointy 0.32
# 12: black   flat 0.32

# B
widgets[,{
    totwt = sum(weight)
    .SD[,.(frac=sum(weight)/totwt),by=style]
},by=color]
 #    color  style      frac
 # 1:   red  round 0.3466667
 # 2:   red pointy 0.3466667
 # 3:   red   flat 0.3066667
 # 4: green pointy 0.3333333
 # 5: green   flat 0.3200000
 # 6: green  round 0.3466667
 # 7:  blue   flat 0.3866667
 # 8:  blue  round 0.2933333
 # 9:  blue pointy 0.3200000
# 10: black  round 0.3733333
# 11: black pointy 0.3333333
# 12: black   flat 0.2933333
```

*How it works*: Construct your denominator for the top-level group (`color`) before going to the finer group (`color` with `style`) to tabulate.

---

*Alternatives*. If `style`s repeat within each `color` and this is only for display purposes, try a `table`:

```
# A
widgets[,
  prop.table(table(color,style),1)
]
#        style
# color   flat pointy round
#   black 0.32   0.32  0.36
#   blue  0.36   0.32  0.32
#   green 0.32   0.36  0.32
#   red   0.32   0.32  0.36

# B
widgets[,rep(1L,sum(weight)),by=.(color,style)][,
  prop.table(table(color,style),1)
]

#        style
# color        flat    pointy     round
#   black 0.2933333 0.3333333 0.3733333
#   blue  0.3866667 0.3200000 0.2933333
#   green 0.3200000 0.3333333 0.3466667
#   red   0.3066667 0.3466667 0.3466667
```

For B, this expands the data so that there is one observation for each unit of weight. With large data, such an expansion would be a bad idea (since it costs so much memory). Also, `weight` has to be an integer; otherwise, its sum will be silently truncated to one (e.g., try `rep(1,2.5) # [1] 1 1`).

Comment: This is what I do, but I'd be interested in finding a better way, too.

Comment: Thanks @Frank -- it is going to take me a while to grok the dot notation and the embedded assignments, but this is a great approach.

Comment: Your first version can be rewritten without temp variable as follows: `widgets[, .(frac = .SD[, .N, by=style]$N / .N), by=color]`

Comment: @Arun The `style` column should be in the result, too.

Answer (score 2):

it may be a good idea to use `dplyr`

```
df <- widgets %>% 
  group_by(color, style) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = count/sum(count))

df2 <- widgets %>% 
  group_by(color, style) %>%
  summarise(count_w = sum(weight)) %>%
  mutate(freq = count_w/sum(count_w))
```

Comment: Thanks @drsh1 I appreciate that `dplyr` is intuitive and useful here.  My question specifically though was how to use `data.table` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate a frequency table for each `style` within `color` and then for each row look up the frequency for that row's `style` in that table finally dividing by the number of rows within that `color`.

```
widgets[, frac := table(style)[style] / .N, by = color]
```

giving:

```
  > widgets
     serial_no color  style weight frac
  1:         1   red  round      1 0.36
  2:         2 green pointy      2 0.36
  3:         3  blue   flat      3 0.36
  4:         4 black  round      4 0.36
  5:         5   red pointy      5 0.32
  6:         6 green   flat      1 0.32
  7:         7  blue  round      2 0.32
  8:         8 black pointy      3 0.32
  9:         9   red   flat      4 0.32
 10:        10 green  round      5 0.32
 ... etc ...
```

This could readily be translated to base or dplyr, if desired:

```
# base
prop <- function(x) table(x)[x] / length(x)
transform(widgets, frac = ave(style, color, FUN = prop))

# dplyr - uses prop function from above
library(dplyr)
widgets %>% group_by(color) %>% mutate(frac = prop(style)) %>% ungroup
```